# Model not training in Pytorch with hugginface

Tags: pytorch

I am using a sentence transformer from huggin face to create custom embeddings.

I have a dataset of shape:

```
text1 | text2 |label|

blabb | blab2 |  1  |
abbas | blab2 |  0  |
```

where I have pairs of sentences and a label indicating similarity (1) and dissimilarity (0).

I would like thus to fine tune a model based on this. My code:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)  # Adjust the learning rate as needed

# Binary Cross Entropy (BCE) loss
loss_function = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

embedding_model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L12-v2').to(device)

# TRAINING Example: Iterate through the train_dataLoader
for epoch in range(10):
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        text_data1, text_data2, labels = batch['text_data1'], batch['text_data2'], batch['labels']
        
       
        embeddings1 = model.embedding_model.encode(text_data1, convert_to_tensor=True)
        embeddings2 = model.embedding_model.encode(text_data2, convert_to_tensor=True)
        cosine_similarities = F.cosine_similarity(embeddings1, embeddings2, dim=-1)

        
        output = torch.tensor(cosine_similarities, requires_grad=True)
        output = output.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        loss = loss_function(output.squeeze(), labels.float())

        # Backward pass and optimization for the sentence embedding model
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

The problem is that after each epoch the loss does not change at all. inspecting the model parameters. I also see that they do not change. Adding a torch linear layer at the end of this model makes the loss change since the parameters of this layer do change. i have also tried to use a single batch for training ad i see that the loss remains constant for each round.

So, I conclude that the gradients are not computed for the sentence transformer mode land it does not change at all after every round. However I would like to fine tune it to my problem.

What am I missing? i think it is something simple, yet I have not found a solution to it.

Comment: Have you tried using `model.train(True)`

Comment: @Djinn this method was true by default inspected it. Unfortunatelly, the problem persists.